# In RCP / Plugin development, what should be written for properties, args, and values to be written in 'activewhen' and 'enabledwhen'?

Tags: eclipse, plugins, swt, rcp

I am currently developing RCP.

The first picture plugin.xml file is included in the com.aaa.bbb.core project.

[image]

And the plugin.xml file in the second picture is included in the com.ccc.ddd.validator project.

[image]

What I'm trying to do is disable the popup's menu if there is no name(assist-provider) for the selected item on the UI.

The list of items that can be selected on the UI refers to the extension points of the com.ccc.ddd.validator project in the second figure, and only some of these extension points have the name (assist-provider) property as indicated by the red square. You have.

I don't know how to write conditions (property, args, value, etc.) in the com.aaa.bbb.core.command.assistValidationResult extension point in the com.aaa.bbb.core project with the above content.

The menu popup is always displayed, but I think you should use enabledwhen not activewhen because it will only be disabled depending on the situation.

Any advice on the matter would be appreciated.

Comment: Those fields are specific to those extension points. You have to look at the documentation for the extension points to know what is required.

Comment: @greg-449 Thanks, So does this mean that in the com.aaa.bbb.core project you can't declare the extension point for the com.ccc.ddd.validator project?

Comment: If a plugin declares an extension point then any other plugin can use that extension point. What the values of the extension point properies mean depends on the plugin that declared the extension point.